# Replace ascii codes with strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, ascii

I created a simple javascript function that receives a string and parses through it and updates other form fields. The function is called when I use a scanner to read a 2D barcode.  My problem is that there are multiple fields separated with ascii code 29 which is the "group separator".  I'm trying convert all the special characters to a readable string like "". I tried doing a replace like:

var BC = barcodestring.replace(String.fromCharCode(29), '');

Also, will the "replace" function replace just 1 or all of the occurrences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to replace the default replace function to it replaces all of that character.

```
barcodestring  = barcodestring.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(29).replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'g'), "")
```